# Approach where features are combination of text(labels) and numerical

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to figure out a good approach for a data set that includes text, which are really more like labels and numeric data. For example, in the data set, I have city, state, lat/lon and I want to classify. This is supervised, I have labels (y) for the data.

So in this case, the text is really not something to bag of words on or something like that. It is really just a label, more like 0, 1, ... However, I don't ~think~ I want to give the algorithm the idea that these are real values. I have tried a couple of different algos including svm.SVC and LinearSVC, and DecisionTree. For the svm, I converted the city and state to numeric values using a couple of different methods including LabelEncoder. But this doesn't seem right intuitively and I am not satisfied with the score.

Any thoughts or input are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder). For an explanation take a look at the [Encoding categorical features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features) section of the docs. The idea is that you will make a column for each city with 0/1 values if the sample belongs to the current city. You might also be interested in [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#dict-feature-extraction).